# Create a simple batch file that extract, install and more

Tags: batch-file, zip, extract

One of my daily task at work, is to extract the content from a **downloaded** **ZIP FILE** into a **USB STICK drive** that must be quickly formatted in **FAT32**.

After I extract the **ZIP File** into the **USB STICK**, there is one file in particular (called **setup.bat**) that I need to **right click and select Run as Administrator.**

The final step is to eject the **USB STICK** from the computer and give the **USB STICK** to a sales person.

Now my question is, can I create a **batch file** that does this job for me?  I insert the **USB STICK drive** into the machine and I run the **BATCH FILE,** everything can be done automatically?

**Step #1**
Insert the USB Stick (Of course this is a manual step from me.)

**Step #2**
Run the batch file that we create.

**Step #3**
The batch file executes: Quick format the USB Stick in FAT32
I do not need to give a name to the volume. It can be empty.

**Step #4**
The batch file executes: Extract the content from the ZIP FILE located into the downloads folder into the USB Stick.
(The name of the zip file is: plc-stick_8.3)

**Step #5**
The batch file executes: Run as Administrator a specific file: setup.bat
This is a file located within the package that has been extracted from the zip file into the USB Stick.

**Step #6**
The batch file executes: Unmount/Eject the USB Stick

Thank you so much in advance for your help and have a beautiful day

**sambul35**
*thank you so much for your help.  It is almost done and perfect.  I only received a couple of warning message.  I am pretty sure this is something that I am missing from your conditions.  Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?  You can read the execution below.  Thank you so much again.*

---

```
The type of the file system is FAT32.
QuickFormatting 1.9 GB
Initializing the File Allocation Table (FAT)...
Format complete.
       1.9 GB total disk space.
       1.9 GB are available.

        4,096 bytes in each allocation unit.
      490,432 allocation units available on disk.

           32 bits in each FAT entry.

Volume Serial Number is 2495-4F8F

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

Unpack completed. Running setup...

The system cannot find the path specified.
'bootinst.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Install completed

'removedrive' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
All tasks done. Remove Flash Drive.
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: I just found the command line for formatting.  I am referring to step #3. 

format /FS:FAT32 /Q D:

Comment: Now I need to know how to make step #4

Comment: Whats OS version do you use? Are all USB Flash Drives of the same make, model and size? Are they new preformatted to FAT from factory, or used with existing filesystem, or not formatted at all? To what drive letter they are usually automounted on your PC?

Comment: Also, what does the setup.bat do? Can you disable UAC control on your PC for these tasks, so you don't have to run it as Admin?

Comment: Or post the code of _setup.bat_ here to help you out.

Comment: Windows 7 Professional - All the USB Flash Drives are the same model and same zie.  They are FAT formatted from factory - D is the letter

Comment: I should be able to disable UAC control on the PC that I am using for this type of task.

Comment: The setup.bat file contain the following: @echo off cd slap\boot bootinst.bat

Answer (score 0):

The batch below performs all the tasks you need. It makes several assumptions:

- the USB Thumb drives you process are preformatted at factory with one   existing partition
- thumbs are always automounted upon hookup to the same drive letter *D:* . You can change
  the drive letter in the script
- you downloaded, unpacked and copied to this batch directory
  [RemoveDrive](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html) tool. Its the best way to eject a USB flash drive
  from Cmd
- you didn't move your user account Downloads folder from its default
  location
- save this *AutoFlash.bat* in your user account accessible directory,
  create a desktop shortcut to it, select in its
  *Properties-Shortcut-Advanced* option "*Run as Administrator*"

If these conditioned are met, hook up a USB Thumb, wait until its accessible in Windows Explorer, then run this script by the shortcut to auto perform all your tasks:

```
<!-- : Begin batch script
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /d %~dp0 & set "drive=D:" & set "mount=0" & echo/
set "file=%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\plc-stick_8.3.zip"
if exist %drive%\nul (format %drive% /q /fs:FAT32 /Y /v:USBFlash
) else (set "mount=1" & echo Flash drive is not mounted)
timeout 3
if not %mount% equ 1 (echo/
    cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" "%file%" "%drive%\"
    echo Unpack completed. Running setup... & echo/
    call %drive%\setup.bat
    timeout 3 & echo Install completed & echo/
    removedrive %drive% -L
    echo All tasks done. Remove Flash Drive.
) else (echo/ & echo Reinsert the drive or open Disk Management)
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
exit /b

----- Begin wsf script --->
<job><script language="VBScript">
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(1))
Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
</script></job>
```

Let me know if there're any problems running the script.

Comment: @user2823725 When running the above script, no need to disable UAC, as the batch runs as Admin from shortcut.

Comment: @user2823725 If the script works for you, consider upvoting AND accepting the answer in this thread by clicking "Arrow Up" and "Select" signs to the left of the answer. :)

Comment: sambul35 please my original message please. thank you so much

Comment: Regarding `bootinst.bat`: in what _drive\dir_
 the folder `slap\boot` is created? Also, did you download [RemoveDrive](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html) tool, and where it's unpacked and saved?